# rundeck unable to execute powershell script with import-module

Tags: python, powershell, rundeck

I am running several python scripts via rundeck (in-line) on windows 2012 target node. These scripts used to run locally but now in the process of moving to rundeck.

One of the python scripts opens subprocess to invoke a powershell script and read the output.

```
import subprocess
CMD = [r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe ', '-File', r'C:\Users\Osman\Code\mop.ps1']
cmd = CMD[:]
cmd.append('arg1')
cmd.append('arg2')
cmd.append('arg3')
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
r = p.communicate()
print(r)
```

The mop.ps1 is

```
Import-Module MSOnline
$domain = $args[0]
$login = $args[1]
$pass = $args[2]
$EPass = $pass | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($login, $EPass)
Connect-MsolService -Credential $Cred
$TenantId = Get-MsolPartnerContract -Domain $domain | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TenantId
Get-MsolAccountSKU -TenantId $TenantId | select SkuPartNumber,ActiveUnits,ConsumedUnits | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This part of the code always fails to execute and if I check stderr it says:

```
        Connect-MsolService : Exception of type 'Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException' was thrown.
At C:\Users\Osman\Code\mop.ps1:7 char:1 
+ Connect-MsolService -Credential $Cred
```

I'm not sure why it fails. I tried

```
Import-Module MSOnline -Verbose
```

And I can see Cmdlets being loaded. I tried creating profile.ps1 file in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\` location.

Everything works fine if I execute the code locally. I tried running a regular test .ps1 file 'disk.ps1' instead of my code, and that works fine because it doesn't load any modules:

```
get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $env:computername
```

What's the workaround to get a script with module to run properly? stdout is always empty.

Node is registered as 64 bit so I tried changing the cmd to

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

I tried to copy profile.ps1 there, copied the Module there but still doesn't work via rundeck.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, since you are able to get a valid output when running the script directly from the server, it may be possible that you error could be related to the “[Second Hop](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-second-hop-functionality-with-credssp/)” that you use to login into MS-Online. Currently, the [Rundeck Python-Winrm plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin) supports Basic, ntlm or CredSSP Authentication, and CredSSP authentication allows you to perform the second hop successfully.